# Android Loading Large JSON file every time Java

Tags: java, android, json, openweathermap, weather-api

I am trying to make a android weather app with open weather API.

But one thing bugs me is how to get the location list and allow the user to add a new location

I found a json file from open weather, but the **file is fairly large**. **If I read the file every time users start the app, it would take at least 5 seconds.**

So, is there a better approach to solve this issue?

Comment: Try saving the downloaded json file locally so user doesn't need to wait for the 5 seconds every time the app runs. Then you can download the json in background in case the json file has changed and overwrite your local json file silently.

Comment: There are some options such as: 1. cache the data. For example, use SQLite to store the data (but don't forget to cleanup obsolete data periodically); 2. try to split the request to get the data part by part, use additional filtering/query conditions to make the result JSON smaller; 3. make requests in background; 4. don't use object mapping, use stream-oriented parsing (for example, look at https://github.com/anatolygudkov/green-jelly, Jackson and Gson also support such tokenizer-based parsing)...